# iPad Air 2 time-lapse maximum length?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, camera

I'd like to record a two-day long time-lapse video with iPad Air 2.

How long can iPad Air 2 record (charging while recording) time-lapse video in iOS 8.1.2?

Answer (score 1):

I would say until it uses up all its storage. How long it takes to do that would depend on the scene being shot and how long the intervals between taking photos are.

Answer (score 1):

It can take a time lapse as long as it has battery. If you plug it in it will go until something stops working or you end it. Storage space is not a problem because it discards half the frames after a certain period of time and doesn't take up any more storage on a seven day time lapse Than it does on a one hour one. Seven days is the longest I've gone and it was with an old iPhone 4s. Hope this helps